# What does the "check" command do in Frozen Synapse?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I've noticed that there is an order you can give to your units called "Check".

However, the tutorial doesn't explain what it is and I can't really tell what it does.

What is this for, and when should I use it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe this forces your unit to look in that specific direction without necessarily aiming down the sight or decreasing his movement speed.  It's a momentary glance so he will engage targets in that direction, then continue on hustling at full speed.

Comment: confirmed, the dude just glances in that direction and then carries on